# How to use form submit to load img tag using post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post

I have an interactive plotting form like below:

```
<form method="post">
    <img src="plot.cgi" alt="[plot]">
    <input type="text" name="plot_settings" value="Type plot settings here.">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="plot it">
</form>
```

(Simplified to the bare minimum above to show the point.)

The image is generated by `plot.cgi`, which sends the browser the new plot. At present, the user clicks the "plot it" button and the whole page reloads, but I'd like just the image to reload. Obviously, I could script each input into a GET request address and replace the `img` `src` with that, but post is more desirable, and it seems there should be a more elegant way to make use of the form's submit mechanism.

Is there a way to load the `img` using POST instead of setting a GET string to it's `src`?

(jQuery is okay.)

Comment: I don't get it. What do you mean reload the image? Do you mean change the src link? If so, just use JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery('form[method="post"]').submit( function( evt ) {
  var url = jQuery(this).target();
  var data = jQuery(this).serialize();
  jQuery.post( url, data, function(data) {
    jQuery(this).find('img').src( data.plotURL ); // use server-generated URL for plot img
  });
  evt.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: This would seem to work better in cases where the server generated links to newly created static images, unless I read it wrong... The page still reloads when implementing this method, despite the inclusion of `evt.preventDefault()`.